# PyQt5 How to GET widths of QTableWidget column(s)

Tags: pyqt5

I have researched this all day via Google without success.

I have a QTableWidget which I populate with two columns set to resize according to their content.

I now want to retrieve the column widths.

There does not appear to be a QTableWidget property exposing this value. Can some kind person please put me out of my misery (no, not with a smoking gun ...)?

Comment: [`QTableWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html) inherits [`QTableView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html), which has the relevant property.

Comment: Thanks ekhumoro - I found it when I looked more carefully. Growing old (sigh!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `QTableWidget.columnWidth(<index of column>)`, if w is your tablewidget:

```
for i in range(w.columnCount()):
    print(w.columnWidth(i))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not seeing a 'columnWidth(n)' method in autocompletion, so was blind-sided. It works as you wrote and is EXACTLY what I was expecting to find. Groan. (Crawls back under rock, mumbling ...)

Comment: I lied! It IS there in autocompletion! Tired eyes make mistakes. Sorry for troubling you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to resize columns by content is to use this `resizeColumnsToContents()`